# how to disable back button- browser without using javascript i want to use servlet

Tags: java, spring

I am facing problems in my application(built using JSP/servlet) when the user clicks browser's back button.How the servlet should be coded in such way that it detects browser's back button event and performs no action.I am not allowed to use Javascript.

Comment: Don't even try to mess around with the behaviour of the built-in browser buttons. For one thing, it makes for a very poor UX if browser buttons don't do what they're supposed to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the pages are been requested from the browser cache. You'll need to disable the client-side caching of the pages in question. You can do this by creating a Filter which listens on an url-pattern of the pages you'd like to disable the cache for, such as *.jsp. Do the following in the doFilter() method:

```
HttpServletResponse httpres = (HttpServletResponse) response;
httpres.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
httpres.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
httpres.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Java Code will be executed on server side.
2. Javascript runs on client.

Its not possible to disable browser back button in `Java`, however you can choose what to do when such an event occurs. You can choose to show the same page.

Comment: im using this code in java script  :     window.history.forward();
 function noBack(){
  window.history.forward();
  }
 but it's working very slow it goes to back page then reloads the current  page in that time period we can prevent to execute tha script code that's why i want to code and fix it by java code.

Comment: You can write filters for it.